# Problem with code not executing while using Marshal class

Tags: c#

I've been writing a low-level keyboard hook in c#. It works great, after pressing any key, the callback method is executed, but if I try to use something like `Marshal.ReadInt32` or `Marshal.Copy` inside that callback method then my code stops executing in the place I've used `Marshal` class, it's like using `Marshal` class works like a return statement.

```
private static IntPtr OnKeyEvent(int code, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)   
{
    Console.WriteLine("Before");
    int wP = Marshal.ReadInt32(wParam);            
    Console.WriteLine("After");

    return CallNextHookEx(IntPtr.Zero, code, wParam, lParam);
}
```

The result of it is :

[image: Before,Before,Before,Before,Before etc]

If I comment out the Marshal.ReadInt32 line :

[image: Before,After,Before,After etc]

Why is that?

Comment: I'm guessing that you are getting an Exception.  If you wrap the code in a `try...catch` block and process any Exception that is generated?

Comment: Looking again, `wParam` could actually just contain the `int` value you are looking for, **not** a pointer to unmanaged memory.  Have you tried debugging and taking a look at what is in `wParam`?

Comment: The code throw an exception, maybe your wParam is not an int, try to parse the value or wrap the code with try catch like Martin said

Comment: Is wParam == null?

Comment: Ok, so it actually throws an AccessViolationException, and values of wParam are always 0x0100 for key press and 0x0101 for key release. So that means that wParam is actually just a value, and I got an exception while trying to get to memory on those wierd adresses(0x0100 and 0x0101) huh?

Comment: wParam is the keyboard message, 0x100 for WM_KEYDOWN and 0x101 for WM_KEYUP.  You probably meant to pass lParam, the ReadInt32() will then return the virtual key number.  The OS can't allow the callback to die on an exception, that would make the user lose control of the keyboard.  So it swallows the exception without a peep.  The debugger sees it, look in the Output window.  Forcing it to stop on the exception is possible, but no keyboard.  That doesn't last forever however, another countermeasure the OS uses is to completely disable the hook after 5 seconds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this:

```
int wP = wParam.ToInt32();
```

It seems you are installing the Keyboard hook for WH_KEYBOARD_LL or WH_KEYBOARD. In this case, the wParam value contains either WM_KEYDOWN (0x0100) or WM_KEYUP (0x0101) - as you say. and you can get the virtual keycode from lParam - which should be a valid Pointer. So you can use your marshal function for lParam:

```
int keyCode = Marshal.ReadInt32(lParam);
```

Comment: wParam is always 0x0100 for keypress and 0x0101 for keyrelease, so it can't be keycode...

Comment: Ok, at least we know then: it's not a valid pointer into a memory location. And that's the reason why an exception was thrown in your original version.

Comment: It seems you are installing the Keyboard hook for WH_KEYBOARD_LL or WH_KEYBOARD. In this case, the wParam value contains either WM_KEYDOWN (0x0100) or WM_KEYUP (0x0101) - as you say. and you can get the virtual keycode from lParam - which should be an valid Pointer. So you can use your marshal function for lParam:

    Marshal.ReadInt32(lParam)

Comment: I edited my original answer to reflect this finding.

Answer (score 2):

You can check this how to do it right.

https://github.com/Alois-xx/etwcontroller/blob/master/ETWController/Hooking/Hooker.cs

```
public int KeyboardHook(int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
{
    if (nCode >= 0)
    {
        var keyboardData = (HookNativeDefinitions.KeyboardHookStruct)Marshal.PtrToStructure(lParam, typeof(HookNativeDefinitions.KeyboardHookStruct));
        unchecked
        {
            // wParam is WM_KEYDOWN, WM_KEYUP, WM_SYSKEYDOWN, or WM_SYSKEYUP
            int wInt = wParam.ToInt32();
            var key = KeyInterop.KeyFromVirtualKey((int)keyboardData.vkCode);
            if (wInt == WM.KEYDOWN || wInt == WM.SYSKEYDOWN && OnKeyDown != null)
            {
                OnKeyDown?.Invoke(key);
            }
            else
            {

            }
        }

    }

    return HookNativeDefinitions.CallNextHookEx(MouseHookHandle, nCode, wParam, lParam);
}
```

Your example crashes because you try to dereference e.g. (void *) 100 == WM_KEYDOWN for the various window messages. You need to convert the wParam to an integer and then convert the lParam to a KeyboardStruct structure where you get the actual keycode out from it.